# How to handle multiple multiple user types?

Tags: django, rest, authentication, django-rest-framework

I'm working on a `RESTful` Django app that requires two types of users: `regular` and `privileged` users. Both users will have different ways to authenticate into the app:

1) `Regular` users: will authenticate with `phone number` and `password`
2) `Privileged` users: will authenticate with `email` and `password`

What is a good strategy to handle this type of authentication system? Is there a way to dynamically authenticate using different methods (`phone number` and `email`) based on the type of user logging in?

Answer (score 2):

Adding a flag to define the type of user and applying checks accordingly will be a good idea.

In your model,

```
REGULAR = 'r'
PRIVILEGED = 'p'
USER_TYPE = (
    (REGULAR, 'Regular'),
    (PRIVILEGED, Privileged'),
)

type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=USER_TYPE, default=REGULAR)
```

Add checks in your views, services and templates accordingly.

Comment: Should I use a generic `CharField` to capture both the phone number and email?

Comment: @ttmtran Django has `EmailField` already. For `phone_number` Yes.